# Generalizing characterizing crystalline representations of dimension 2 to certain special classes of crystalline representations of higher dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, p-adic-hodge-theory

Let $A$ be an abelian variety defined over a number field $K$, and let $v$ be a prime of $K$ such that $A$ has good reduction modulo $v$. Let $\rho$ be the representation of $G_K = \text{Gal}(\overline{K}/K)$ on the etale cohomology of $A$. Then it is known (by Coleman and Iovita) that the restricted representation $\rho |_{K_v}$ is a *crystalline representation*.

It is known that crystalline representations correspond to *weakly admissible filtered $(\phi, N)$-modules*, by the work of Fontaine (see these notes by [Fontaine and Ouyang](https://www.math.u-psud.fr/~fontaine/galoisrep.pdf)) . In other words, they are parametrized by triples $(W, \phi, F)$, where $W$ is a $K_v$-vector space, $\phi$ a semilinear Frobenius operator, and $F$ a filtration of $W$, satisfying some compatibility conditions (weakly admissible).

There is also a full characterization of irreducible crystalline representations of dimension 2. Indeed, they are completely characterized by the characteristic polynomial of the Frobenius (see, for example, Section 8 of these notes by [Brinon and Conrad](http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/notes.pdf)). The reason why things work out so nicely is because there aren't too many possibilities for the Hodge filtration.

So my question is, can something like the 2-dimensional case be recovered in a very specific case? Here we are looking for triples $(W, \phi, F)$ where $W$ is a $2d$-dimensional $K_v$-vector space, and $F$ is a *two-step* filtration. That is, we have $F^0 W = W, F^1 W = V, F^2 W = \{0\}$, where $V$ is a $d$-dimensional $K_v$-vector space. One can further assume that the characteristic polynomial of $\phi$ acting on $W$ is *pure*, so that it is defined over $\mathbb{Z}$ and its roots are all Weil numbers.